# Octave configure cannot find Qt library on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, octave

I have installed QT 4.8 library on my OS X through direct install with .dmg file downloaded from qt-project.org. It seems a framework version. And so far, a lot of tools recognises it well. But when I am building octave on this computer, it gives a warning of "Qt libraries not found". I wonder why. And what can I do to make it recognise the qt lib on my machine.

The command I used for configure is

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared F77=gfortran-4.2 LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib'
```

---

(further information)

I did tried to find the installation of QT with

```
find find /Library/ -name QtGui
```

Returning result being

```
/Library//Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui
/Library//Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QtGui
/Library//Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
```

Along with the fact that `ipython notebook --matplotlib=qt` is working well on my system, I assume my Qt Library is successfully installed.

But when performing the check with `pkg-config`, both `pkg-config --cflag QtGui` and `pkg-config --libs QtGui` return no positive result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the answer now. qt-4.8 installed through .dmg file is a framework version. There is no `Qt*.pc` file, thus is not able to be found by `pkg-config`. So, in order to use `pkg-config` to find qt installed in the system, you need to build qt from source(source downloadable from qt-project.org), specifying that a `-no-framework` version is to be built:

```
./configure -no-framework --foo --bar
make
sudo make install
```

After building and installing, qt would be located in(by default)

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Thus adding a line to ~/.bashrc

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/pkgconfig/:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
```

would help `pkg-config` locating the qt in your system.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your effort and answer, this will help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Qt installation is working. I'll assume it was correctly installed and is visible to the operating system you're using.

The `configure` command you have pasted accepts two environment variables, `QT_CFLAGS` and `QT_LIBS`. Use the `pkg-config` tool to determine their appropriate values:

```
pkg-config --cflags QtGui
pkg-config --libs QtGui
```

and add this information to the command line:

```
./configure QT_CFLAGS='foo' QT_LIBS='bar' # other stuff...
```

Comment: I tried the commands, yet pkg-config cannot locate QtGui. But I tried `find \Library\ -name QtGui`, there are several results lying in `/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/`. I think QtGui is recognised by the system, as earlier on, I used ipython notebook with qt, and it's working well.

Comment: @Chong, see if you can find `QtGui.pc` somewhere on the filesystem. This is the file `pkg-config` will be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed QT by .run file, you might find pkgconfig folder. For me, I have installed QT to "/opt/qt5.15.x/" and I find this path "/opt/qt5.15.x/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig". Referencing [pkg-config-path-environment-variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable), I add it to PKG_CONFIG_PATH by

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/qt5.15.x/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig/
```

And then, Octave configure find QT. And it's better to check the .pc file in your pkgconfig folder. "prefix" in the .pc files might be wrong.